# Javascript iterate through JSON file levels to populate dropdown list

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu

I'mn new to JS and trying to pass values from a JSON file to populate dropdown lists. I've got a JSON file that looks like this:

```
var mydates = {
   "2018": {
       "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
       "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
       "March": ["week8","week9","week11"]
   },
   "2019": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8","week10","week11"]
    },
    "2020": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8"]
    }
}
```

I want a first dropdown list to show the years listed, a second dropdown for the months and a last dropdown for the weeks.

I came up with the following to populate the dropdown  for years with id "selectedyear", and it works just fine:

```
years = []
for(var prop in mydates){
    console.log(prop)
    years.push(prop)}

var myyear = document.getElementById('selectedyear');
for(var i = 0; i < years.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = years[i];
    myyear.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Now how can I iterate through the second level of the JSON so that the options for the dropdown with id "selectedmonth" only shows the months for the year selected, and then for the dropdown with id "selectedweek" to show the weeks corresponding to the selected year and month ??

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you want to show 3 dropdown elements at once, or one dynamic dropdown?

Comment: Three dropdown elements at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code both initiallizes and listens for event `change` of any selection excluding the week selection.

```
const mydates = {
    "2018": {
        "January": ["week1", "week2", "week3", "week4"],
        "February": ["week5", "week6", "week7"],
        "March": ["week8", "week9", "week11"]
    },
    "2019": {
        "January": ["week1", "week2", "week3", "week4"],
        "February": ["week5", "week6", "week7"],
        "March": ["week8", "week10", "week11"]
    },
    "2020": {
        "January": ["week1", "week2", "week3", "week4"],
        "February": ["week5", "week6", "week7"],
        "March": ["week8"]
    }
}

const years = Object.keys(mydates); // years = ['2018', '2019', '2020']
const initalMonths = Object.keys(Object.values(mydates)[0]);
const initialWeeks = mydates[Object.keys(mydates)[0]][initalMonths[0]];

const $yearSelectionOBJ = document.getElementById('selecetedyear');
const $monthSelectionOBJ = document.getElementById('selecetedmonth');
const $weekSelectionOBJ = document.getElementById('selecetedweek');

for (year of years) {
    const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

    $optOBJ.innerHTML = year;
    $yearSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
}

for (month of initalMonths) {
    const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

    $optOBJ.innerHTML = month;
    $monthSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
}

for (week of initialWeeks) {
    const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

    $optOBJ.innerHTML = week;
    $weekSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
}

$yearSelectionOBJ.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    $monthSelectionOBJ.innerHTML = '';
    $weekSelectionOBJ.innerHTML = '';

    for (month in mydates[event.target.value]) {
        const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

        $optOBJ.innerHTML = month;
        $monthSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
    }

    for (week of mydates[event.target.value][Object.keys(mydates[event.target.value])[0]]) {
        const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

        $optOBJ.innerHTML = week;
        $weekSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
    }
});

$monthSelectionOBJ.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    $weekSelectionOBJ.innerHTML = '';

    for (week of mydates[$yearSelectionOBJ.value][$monthSelectionOBJ.value]) {
        const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

        $optOBJ.innerHTML = week;
        $weekSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to use an onchange event from the selection of a new value to populate the values of the other dropdowns. Below is an example.

```js
const mydates = {
    "2018": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8","week9","week11"]
    },
    "2019": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8","week10","week11"]
    },
    "2020": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8"]
    }
};

const yearSelect = document.getElementById("year");
for (let year in mydates) {
    let opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = year;
    yearSelect.appendChild(opt);
}

const monthSelect = document.getElementById("month");
const weekSelect = document.getElementById("week");

// delete all options besides the placholder
function clearSelect(select) {
    select.querySelectorAll("option:not(.placeholder)").forEach(elem => {
        select.removeChild(elem);
    });
}

function yearChanged(year) {
    monthSelect.querySelector("option.placeholder").innerHTML = "Select a month";
    clearSelect(monthSelect);
    // add options for the given year
    for (let month in mydates[year]) {
        let opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = month;
        monthSelect.appendChild(opt);
    }
    monthSelect.value = '';  // select the placeholder

    clearSelect(weekSelect);
    weekSelect.querySelector("option.placeholder").innerHTML = "Select a month first";
    weekSelect.value = '';  // select the placeholder
}

function monthChanged(month) {
    weekSelect.querySelector("option.placeholder").innerHTML = "Select a week";
    clearSelect(weekSelect)
    for (const week of mydates[yearSelect.value][month]) {
        let opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = week;
        weekSelect.appendChild(opt);
    }
    weekSelect.value = '';  // select the placeholder
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <select id="year" onchange="yearChanged(this.value)">
        <option class="placeholder" value="" disabled selected>Select a year</option>
    </select>
    <select id="month" onchange="monthChanged(this.value)">
        <option class="placeholder" value="" disabled selected>Select a year first</option>
    </select>
    <select id="week">
        <option class="placeholder" value="" disabled selected>Select a month first</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks. It works fine when I use your code snippet, but nothing appears on my html. The only difference is the way I call the json file from the static file in Django ... is the issue coming from the below lines since here mydates is not a constant as per your code ?

var mydates;
.fetch("{% static 'dates.json' %}")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => mydates = json)
.then(() => console.log(mydates));

Comment: I can see the json correctly parsed in the console.log ... but on the html the buttons are empty

Comment: Yeah sounds like the parsing is all good. And for scoping, mydates should be available globally so that is not the problem. Did you convert the ids of the selects in the js and html? I used #year, #month, and #date, while I believe you are using #selectedyear, #selectedmonth, and #selecteddate.

Comment: Yes indeed, I changed the ids to match yours. I get the following error now: Uncaught ReferenceError: yearChanged is not defined at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
var mydates = {
   "2018": {
       "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
       "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
       "March": ["week8","week9","week11"]
   },
   "2019": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8","week10","week11"]
    },
    "2020": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8"]
    }
}

var myyear = document.getElementById('selectedyear');
Object.keys(mydates).forEach(year => {
  
  var yearOpt = document.createElement('option');
  yearOpt.innerHTML = year;
  myyear.appendChild(yearOpt);
  
  let months = Object.keys(mydates[year]);
  var myMonth = document.getElementById('selectedmonth');
  months.forEach(month => {
    
    var monthOpt = document.createElement('option');
    monthOpt.innerHTML = month;
    myMonth.appendChild(monthOpt);
    var myWeek = document.getElementById('selectedweek');
    mydates[year][month].forEach(week => {
      let opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.innerHTML = week;
      myweek.appendChild(opt);
    });
  })
})
```